# Exponential moving averages in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

I'm trying to perform the calculation of an exponential moving average of 13 periods but the results don't match at all, I'm using the following code to try to get the result:

```
stockdata['sma'] = stockdata['close'].rolling(window = 13, min_periods=13).mean()
stockdata['ema'] = stockdata['close'].ewm(span=13, adjust=False).mean()
```

simple media is working perfectly, only exponential moving media is not giving the correct values

the calculation of moving averages is done in the column 'close'

```
    ativo  close        sma        ema
0   PETR4  28.18        NaN  28.180000
1   PETR4  28.63        NaN  28.244286
2   PETR4  28.39        NaN  28.265102
3   PETR4  29.18        NaN  28.395802
4   PETR4  28.93        NaN  28.472116
5   PETR4  29.13        NaN  28.566099
6   PETR4  29.48        NaN  28.696656
7   PETR4  30.13        NaN  28.901420
8   PETR4  29.72        NaN  29.018360
9   PETR4  29.42        NaN  29.075737
10  PETR4  29.36        NaN  29.116346
11  PETR4  29.75        NaN  29.206868
12  PETR4  30.55  29.296154  29.398744
```

on the dataframe the oldest data is on top, and the most recent below

the correct value of the exponential moving average of 13 should be 29.53, 
what would be the correct way to use the function?

for the verification that I did on the investment platform, these values ​​that the function is giving me are values ​​of an arithmetic moving average

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're assuming that an EMA with span 13 is *only* looking at the last 13 data points... But that's not really the case, it will look past that date, simply use smaller weights for the data points further in the past...

If you take the last month of closing stock prices for PETR4 and take the 13-day EMA for them, you'll get at the expected result:

```
closing_price = pd.Series([
    30.00, 29.62, 29.29, 29.65, 29.30, 
    28.03, 28.80, 28.85, 28.94, 28.45, 
    28.18, 28.63, 28.39, 29.18, 28.93, 
    29.13, 29.48, 30.13, 29.72, 29.42, 
    29.36, 29.75, 30.55,
])
```

And:

```
In []: closing_price.ewm(span=13, adjust=False).mean().iloc[-1]
Out[]: 29.52974644568118
```

Which after rounding seems to match your expected answer.

Comment: a doubt, should I always consider 23 samples or can this change according to the number of working days in the month?

needed to automate this, it would be great if it were an exact number

Comment: @LeonardoHenriques That's the thing, in theory EWM will use as many data points as you give it, only the ones more distant in the past will have very small weights so won't change the result too much... I think double the "span" is a good estimate of how many you need, but also try giving it more points and seeing at which point it stops affecting the result.